# Why does my debounce not work, yet produce no errors?

Tags: lua, roblox

Why does my debounce not work, yet produce no errors?

Here's my script so far, but it isn't working.

```lua
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local toggle = false

script.Parent.BackpackFrame.Visible = false
script.Parent.BackpackText.Visible = false

UIS.InputBegan:connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E then
        if toggle == false then
            script.Parent.BackpackFrame.Visible = true
            script.Parent.BackpackText.Visible = true
            toggle = true
        end
        
        if toggle == true then
            script.Parent.BackpackFrame.Visible = false
            script.Parent.BackpackText.Visible = false
            toggle = false
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: Not working as in...? What is it supposed to do which it doesn't?

Comment: on a side not: you can assign ```not toggle``` and you will not need handle cases ```toggle  == true``` and ```toggle == false``` differently.

Answer (score 2):

If toggle is false you set it to true

```
if toggle == false then
  script.Parent.BackpackFrame.Visible = true
  script.Parent.BackpackText.Visible = true
  toggle = true
end
```

And then immediately set it to false as you run into your second conditional statement.

```
if toggle == true then
  script.Parent.BackpackFrame.Visible = false
  script.Parent.BackpackText.Visible = false
  toggle = false
end
```

So your change is revoked immediately befor anything had a chance to update.

If you have two exclusive states use if / else.

```
if toggle == false then
  script.Parent.BackpackFrame.Visible = true
  script.Parent.BackpackText.Visible = true
  toggle = true
else
  script.Parent.BackpackFrame.Visible = false
  script.Parent.BackpackText.Visible = false
  toggle = false
end
```

As all you're doing is to assign boolean values you can simply get rid of your conditions and do this:

```
toggle = not toggle -- toggle your state
-- assign the state to the visible property
script.Parent.BackpackFrame.Visible = toggle
script.Parent.BackpackText.Visibile = toggle
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is setting toggle to false immediately after setting it to true.

```
if toggle == false then
   -- false part
   toggle = true
end

if toggle == true then
    -- true part
    toggle = false
end
```

Just use an else instead of checking toggle twice

```
if toggle then
    -- true part
    toggle = false
else
    -- false part
   toggle = true
end
```

Comment: Would this be the script my brain is poop: local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local toggle = false

script.Parent.BackpackFrame.Visible = false
script.Parent.BackpackText.Visible = false

UIS.InputBegan:connect(function(input)
 if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E then
  if toggle == true then
   -- true part
   toggle = false
   script.Parent.BackpackFrame.Visible = false
   script.Parent.BackpackText.Visible = false
  else
   -- false part
   toggle = true
   script.Parent.BackpackFrame.Visible = true
   script.Parent.BackpackText.Visible = true
  end
 end
end)